# STTY cols is not being inherited when connecting to only certain ubuntu servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have a weird with a set of Ubuntu servers running Ubuntu 18.04. 
The issue is as follows if I SSH into the servers the `col` width is 80
which is annoying and I would like to inherit what I have in the client terminal, which happens in all other servers I have access to.

We have not set any custom settings for SSH on the Ubuntu servers, any ideas why this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: Research material: [*How are terminal length and width forwarded over SSH and telnet?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207782/108618) Does the server allocate pseudo-terminal? Is there something in your `ssh` command that would make the server not allocate one?

Comment: I just connect with `ssh user@server` so nothing should alter it